# Google Play inapp billing: where is ClassyTaxiAppWeb?

Tags: java, android, firebase, in-app-billing

On this page:
https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/tree/master/ClassyTaxiJava

is mentioned a 'a read-only web client to access the subscriptions on multiple platforms' but the folder:
https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/tree/master/ClassyTaxiAppWeb

returns a 404 error.

Where can I find the ClassyTaxiAppWeb folder?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the samples over here

https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples

Only server one is here

https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/tree/master/ClassyTaxiServer

[image]

Comment: I am looking for ClassyTaxiAppWeb, not ClassyTaxiServer. Where to find ClassyTaxiAppWeb ?

Comment: https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/tree/master/ClassyTaxiServer/webapp this ?

Comment: Yes, seems to be this ! Google documentation not up to date... Thanks :)

Comment: By the way, what is the purpose of this webapp? I don't understand what is it for.